# Android RecyclerView, alter view based on OnClick.

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have implemented a RecyclerView. I wrote a custom adapter for it. It renders a list of cards with some textView and buttons. I have two buttons inside each card, a plusButton and a minusButton and I want to change the values inside textViews according to click on these Buttons. It does work correctly, but when we scroll down, along with the card which was clicked, another card's textView also gets updated. I know it's happening because the objects are recycled and I use the position in my code. How do I stop it from updating the other cards? Here is the code:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final Product product = productList.get(position);
    holder.productName.setText(product.getName());
    holder.productPrice.setText("$ " + product.getPrice().toString());


    holder.productImage.setImageUrl(product.getImage(), holder.imageLoader);

    //load image and actions for buttons

    array = new int[productList.size()];

    holder.plusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            productList.get(position).setTotal_on_hand(1);
            holder.productQty.setText(product.getTotal_on_hand());
            this.notify();


            Product pr = productList.get(position);
            int pos;
            if (passList.contains(pr)) {
                pos = passList.indexOf(pr);
                array[pos]++;
                priceTotal = priceTotal + pr.getPrice().floatValue();
                qtyTotal++;
                holder.productQty.setText(Integer.toString(array[pos]));
            } else {
                passList.add(pr);
                pos = passList.indexOf(pr);
                array[pos] = 1;
                qtyTotal++;
                priceTotal = priceTotal + pr.getPrice().floatValue();
                holder.productQty.setText(Integer.toString(array[pos]));

            }

            callback.deletePressed();



        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this on your  onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder,int position) method

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final Helper holder, int position) {
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
}
```

Comment: It solves the problem, i.e. it does not update the other cards in the recycler view. But, when I scroll down and the card gets out of view and then scroll back up, it just gets back to it's original state.

Comment: keep a track of things that you are changing.you can use a new arraylist to keep things which you are changing according to position.